# Is it possible to reboot wifi router via http (ajax) request using esp32/esp8266 or API Tester?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, esp32, esp8266

I have an esp8266 device that sends data to the server. It connects wifi router (D-Link DWR921) to get internet access. For several days, it works perfectly, but the wifi router has stuck, and no internet connection, so I have to reboot manually.

The wifi router setting is web-based, and it has a soft button to reboot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8bh6.png)

I have an idea, what if I replace the button with othe by sending HTTP request, so I can make it function in my ESP8266 (if possible)

then I inspect the element the button using a web browser,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9UaD.png)

the reboot button call function named system_reboot()

then I download all of the .html and .js files, and searched about system_reboot(),

```
function system_reboot(){
    var value = 1;
    if( win.confirm(global_lang["login1"]["information"],global_lang["system_popup"]["reboot_dialog"],function (r){
    if(r){systemApi_reboot(value);}
        })){
                }else{return;}
}
```

```
function systemApi_reboot(value) {

            /* Get auth Id */
            cpApi_get_authId();
            
            var post_data={"CfgType":"reboot_reset","cmd": "reboot","authID":auth_id}; 
    
            var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/webpost.cgi",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(post_data),
            dataType: "json"
            });
            
            request.done(function( responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                clearCookies();   
                alert(global_lang['alerts_set']['restart_success']);
                var path = "index.html";
                ProhibitionClick();
                defaultRedirect(120,path,value);
            });
            request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            });
            request.always(function(responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {  
               
            });
}
```

```
function cpApi_get_authId() {
        loginApi_check_auth();

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "/data.ria?token=1",
            type: "GET",           
            dataType: "text",
            async: false
            });
        request.done(function( responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {       
             auth_id = responseData;
        });
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        });
        request.always(function(responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {  
               
        });

}
```

```
function loginApi_check_auth() {
    if (getCookie("qSessId") == null ) {
       
        alert(global_lang['login1']['session-logout']);
        window.location = "index.html";
        return;
    } else {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "login.cgi",
            type: "POST",
            data: { "check_valid" : "qSessId="+getCookie("qSessId")},
            dataType: "json"
        });
        request.done(function( responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {     
           
            if(responseData.login_fail){
               clearCookies();
               alert(global_lang['login1']['session-logout']);
               window.location = "index.html";
               return;
            }
            /* Login is failed */
            if(jqXHR.status == 401) {
                clearCookies();
                window.location = "index.html";
                return;
            }

            /* ReSet the timeout cookie as per latest timeout 
               Note: This happens when you refresh the control panel page and we need to revaidate the cookie            
            */
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 179 * 1000));
            var expires = ";expires=" + date.toGMTString();
            document.cookie ="DWRLOGGEDTIMEOUT="+179+expires;
            global_AuthTimeout = 179; 
            global_authDefaulTimeout = ui_config["login_timeout"];     
        });
        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {      
               clearCookies();
               alert(global_lang['login1']['session-logout']);
               window.location = "index.html";
               return;
          
        });
        request.always(function(  responseData,textStatus, jqXHR ) {
           
        });
  }

}
```

```
function getCookie(c_name)
{
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1)
      {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
      }
    if (c_start == -1)
      {
      c_value = null;
      }
    else
      {
      c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
      var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
      if (c_end == -1)
      {
    c_end = c_value.length;
    }
    c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}
```

Its all of function which is related, my question, is it possible to send HTTP (ajax) request to reboot the router? and how to do that?? I'm confusing...